# How to list all fields in an index that have at least 1 value across a search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm spinning up a set of elasticsearch indices with identical mappings across all of them before any documents are indexed.  For some of these indices, certain fields are never used.

Is there a way to get a list of all fields that are used, given some search query?  For example, imagine a search I perform returns the following single document (or a set of documents with a similar schema to this):

```
{
  type: "foo",
  data: {
    name: "foo",
    address: "bar",
    phoneNumber: "baz"
  }
}
```

I would expect the query I'm asking about to return `[type, data.name, data.address, data.phoneNumber]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could use the meta-field [_field_names](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-field-names-field.html) for this purpose.

Running aggregate on this as shown in the example below would give you the document count too.

Example :

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "Field names": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "_field_names",
            "size": 0
         }
      }
   }
}
```